# opening a temporary tunnel

Tags: shell-script, openssh, port-forwarding

I have the following problem:

I have a remote machine accessible via ssh which can serve some data through a web interface.

I can use OpenSSH LocalForwarding to open a tunnel and start the remote server:

```
ssh user@my.remote.server -L 127.0.0.1:3333:localhost:4000 ./start.sh
```

then, on another terminal (or from GUI), I can start a browser, e.g.:

```
firefox localhost:3333/whatever
```

and access content served by my app.

After use I simply give [CTRL-C] to `start.sh` to close server, connection and tunnel.

So far so good.

Question is: Is it possible to write a script combining everything in such a way the tunnel is closed when browser terminates?

To be more precise I would like a script that:

1. Opens the tunnel and starts remote server (as above).
2. Automatically opens a browser (firefox is ok, but not a must) on the right port (which could be randomly generated).
3. Keeps tunnel up while browser is running.
4. When browser terminates (I am aware there could be other open windows, but that's beyond the point) it should send a signal (`SIGHUP`) to server (`start.sh`).
5. When remote server terminates tunnel should be closed (this should be automatic with the above setup)

I would like to keep tunnel **and** server up-and-running for the time strictly needed, avoiding to "forget closing" as it can happen if I have to do it manually.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out answer is a bit more convoluted than expected.

I ended up writing a full init script for the server:

```
#!/bin/sh

# use start-stop-daemon to control zero-ui
set -e

# Must be a valid filename
NAME=zero-ui
PIDFILE=/home/user/$NAME.pid
DAEMON=/usr/bin/node
DAEMON_OPTS="/home/user/zero-ui/backend/bin/www"

export PATH="${PATH:+$PATH:}/usr/sbin:/sbin"

export NODE_ENV=production
export ZU_SECURE_HEADERS=false
export ZU_SERVE_FRONTEND=true
export ZU_CONTROLLER_TOKEN=...
export ZU_DISABLE_AUTH=true
export ZU_DEFAULT_USERNAME=...
export ZU_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=...

case "$1" in
  start)
        echo -n "Starting daemon: "$NAME
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE -m --exec $DAEMON --chdir /home/user/zero-ui/backend -- $DAEMON_OPTS
        echo "."
    ;;
  stop)
        echo -n "Stopping daemon: "$NAME
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PIDFILE
        echo "."
    ;;

  *)
    echo "Usage: "$1" {start|stop}"
    exit 1
esac

exit 0
```

Then I call it with the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

ssh -n -L 127.0.0.1:3333:localhost:4000 user@server ./start-stop-zeroui start &
firefox localhost:3333/app
ssh user@server ./start-stop-zeroui stop
fg
```

If @larsks or anyone else comes up with a better answer I'll gladly accept their answer, otherwise I'll accept my own in a few days.

I upvoted @larsks because it sparked the idea.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've already outlined most of the steps in your question. This is pretty much what you're asking for:

```
#!/bin/sh

# start ssh in the background, and record the pid in $ssh_pid.
ssh -n -L 127.0.0.1:3333:localhost:4000 user@my.remote.server ./start.sh &
ssh_pid=$!

# start firefox. we're not running it in the background, so the
# script blocks here until firefox terminates.
firefox localhost:3333/whatever

# kill the ssh process
kill $ssh_pid
```

> When remote server terminates tunnel should be closed (this should be automatic with the above setup)

If the remote `./start.sh` command terminates, then `ssh` will exit. This script doesn't take care of quitting firefox in that case, but the tunnel will no longer exist.

Comment: Close, but no cigar. Problem is this closes ssh (and thus tunnel), but remote server is kept running and thus a second run will fail. Difference is you send kill to ssh process while a [CTRL-C] (without `-n` flag) would send a `SIGKILL` to `start.sh` process. I'm unsure about what's actually happening here because `kill -HUP <start.sh PID>` **is** enough and it should be given when connection is closed. May it be `-n` make remote process insensible to hangup? NOTE: if useful I *can* modify `start.sh`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a little surprised the remote server continues running after ssh disconnects. Usually you have to explicitly ignore things like `HUP` for that to happen. If you modify `start.sh` to write a PID to a file, you could `ssh <theserver> sh -c 'kill $(cat pidfile)'`, I guess.

Comment: Sorry, I have a bit of problems with that. `start.sh` scripts has, as its last line `node ./bin/www` and thus it does *not* return till it terminates; how do I get the PID to write? If I get to that I can simply write a `stop.sh` script and call that as `ssh user@server stop.sh`. Should I use something like `/sbin/start-stop-daemon`?